# cPanel not Loading

Tags: dns, cpanel, web-hosting

I just bought my first domain and hosting package, and while I am able to access the front end of my site with the FTP Address, I can't access the cPanel page. I cleared my browser cache and flushed the local DNS cache and it didn't change--and any of my pings timed out. Is cPanel what usually takes a couple hours to access?
Chrome is showing an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Web Hosting for Students

Comment: no access to cpanel from the client area?

Comment: Not from what I can find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cPanel usually takes as long as the front end to load up.

It's likely a problem with your hosting provider, contact them directly. 
 Though it could sort itself out once the host checks on there server status.

Oh I did just remember, some hosts have a dedicated I.P for ftp and won't let you access through any other I.P.

Some very terrible hosts don't allow ftp at all.

Comment: Got it. I've contacted them directly, and I'll check the details of ftp--my instructor specifically recommended this host, so, hopefully, it shouldn't be a very terrible host. Thanks!

Comment: I would if I could, but I don't quite have enough reputation here yet, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're showing "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" means that the WHM / cPanel **Firewall ([csf](https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html)) has blocked your IP**.

**You will need to contact your hosting provider and ask them to remove the IP from the Firewall.**

You should also ask them why your IP is blocked, usually that can be done by their side by doing a quick search through the /var/log files.

For example if you have failed to access your account via FTP more than 5 times in a 10 minute interval you will be blocked and this will be logged in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

Try using different browsers some IP are banned by hosting provider as the firewall is of 2tier otherwise contact your hosting provider for help